# Time consuming query to Skip First inserted record of Id list

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgressql I have a data with multiple articleId list on table. Whereever I query it should skip first inserted record of particular userID in specified list of articleID.

```
select * from (
  select * , row_number() over (partition by articleId order by date) rn
  from table where articleId in (1200) and userId = 1
) t
where t.rn > 1
```

It will return expected record by skip first inserted record of each articleId of particular userId.
But above query consuming more time to execute if there is large data.

table:

| id | name | articleId | date | userId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 1200 | 2021-05-01 06:09:35 | 1 |
| 2 | bcd | 1400 | 2021-05-02 06:08:35 | 1 |
| 3 | xyz | 1200 | 2021-05-03 09:09:35 | 2 |
| 4 | pqr | 1200 | 2021-05-04 08:09:35 | 1 |
| 5 | xyz | 1200 | 2021-05-05 09:09:35 | 3 |

Expected query Output:

| id | name | articleId | date | userId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | pqr | 1200 | 2021-05-04 08:09:35 | 1 |

Comment: Because userId is different. query expecting userId=1.

Comment: Oh, I loose `and userId = 1` in subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following index, which should cover the call to `ROW_NUMBER` as well as the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx ON yourTable (articleId, date, userId);
```

This should speed up your current query.  As always, check the execution plan before and after using `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a correlated subquery with the right indexing:

```
select * 
from t
where t.articleid = 1200 and t.userId = 1 and
      t.date > (select min(t2.date)
                from t t2
                where t2.articleId = t.articleId
               );
```

Then for this query, you want two indexes:  `(articleid, userId)` and `(articleId, date)`.

Note:  I'm a bit surprised that `userId` is not in the `partition by` clause.